# UK visitor visa to study

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I will be visiting the UK from India to do a short research at a university in the UK. From the UK GOV website, I found the following visa type to be most relevant under visit to study option in standard visitor visa:-

- do a short piece of research that’s relevant to your course overseas

However, when I was filling out the visa form, under the question main reason for your visit to the UK when I selected the option "*Short-term study (up to 6 months), including recreational course*", the next page was course enrolment page where I was asked following questions:-

- Are you enrolled or accepted on a UK course, at an accredited institution?
  (Required)
- Is the course you plan on studying a recreational course lasting no longer than 30 days?

I feel this is not the relevant section for me, should I go with *other* option in main reason to visit or something else?

Comment: I'd contact the university's foreign students office for the appropriate guidance

Comment: Typically you’d need a *Standard Visitor visa*, the list of permitted activities for science and academia is here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities

Comment: I was filling out the form for standard visitor, however I am confused for what to select under main reason to visit, here is the link where I found doing a short research option https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-to-study

Answer (score 2):

A *Standard Visitor visa* is the correct option. In addition to fulfilling the suitability and eligibility criteria as a visitor, if you’re visiting to study you must also show that you fulfil the requirements relating to the type of study you will be doing.

For example, to do a short piece of research you must prove that:

> - you’re at least 16 years old
> - you’re already enrolled on a course overseas that is the equivalent of a UK degree
> - you’ve been accepted by a UK higher education institution to take part in research that’s relevant to the course you’re studying overseas.

The institution where you’ll ve doing your research should be able to guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going for the standard visitor option, however under it, these are the options available for the main reasons for stay:
Tourism/Business/Academic/Marriage/Private/Medical/Visit to study/Others.
When I select visit to study it only shows the course enrollment page; however, in UK GOV website visit to study has many options, including short research
Here is the link:- https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-to-study

Comment: @AkshatGautam You can only select between the options given. Try the academic option. AFAIK both require that you’ve been accepted by an institution.